# Sidebar that changes content width

Tags: html, css

I am currently developing a plugin for existing websites.
Its purpose is to display a sidebar with my content. To that end, the website owner creates an empty div, references my javascript file and calls my code with the ID of the empty div.

My plugin is then creating an iFrame in that empty div and loads its content. It also is responsible for styling the provided div so that it actually is a sidebar: It changes the width and height of that div and attaches it to the right edge of the screen.

So, all of that is basically working - loading my iFrame and styling the div.
The problem is that I am not satisfied with the result.

I have tried two different styles for the div:

## Approach 1: float right

I used this CSS:

```
float: right;
height: 100%;
width: 100px;
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't change the total width of the rest of the page. In other words, elements on the website with a `width: 100%` will be shown below my sidebar.

https://jsfiddle.net/DHilgarth/mmzefm14/

## Approach 2: Absolute positioning

I used this CSS:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100px;
```

This approach has the problem that my sidebar now simply overlaps the controls from the website.

https://jsfiddle.net/DHilgarth/34hmnw9h/1/

Is there a way to achieve what I want? A sidebar that basically reduces the available size of the `body` for all elements, except mine?

Answer (score 0):

I have now chosen to actually do exactly what I asked for: I reduce the available width of the body tag.
This is not trivial because of `box-sizing`, padding, margin, border etc and I am sure I have missed a lot of edge cases but for now, the following logic is working for me:

If `box-sizing` is `border-box`: set the right padding of the body element to the width of my sidebar.
Otherwise, set the width of the body element to the width of the body element minus the width of the sidebar. On resize of the window, the width of the body has to be adjusted accordingly.

Code:

```js
function initSidebar() {
  loadSidebar("sidebar");
}

// This code would be loaded from a javascript file I provide

function css(element, property) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property);
}

function getSidebarWidth(sidebarElement) {
 var boundingRect = sidebarElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  return boundingRect.right - boundingRect.left;
}

function styleBorderBoxBody(bodyElement, sidebarElement) {
 bodyElement.style.paddingRight = getSidebarWidth(sidebarElement) + "px";
}

function resizeBody(bodyElement, previousWindowWidth, previousBodyWidth) {
  var currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var newBodyWidth = previousBodyWidth - previousWindowWidth + currentWindowWidth;
  bodyElement.style.width = newBodyWidth + "px";
  return {currentWindowWidth, newBodyWidth};
}

function styleBody(bodyElement, sidebarElement) {
 var boxSizing = css(bodyElement, "box-sizing");
  if(boxSizing == "content-box" || !boxSizing || boxSizing == "") {
   var sidebarWidth = getSidebarWidth(sidebarElement);
    var width = bodyElement.clientWidth - sidebarWidth;
    bodyElement.style.width = width + "px";
    sidebarElement.style.right = (-sidebarWidth) + "px";
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {
     var newWidths = resizeBody(bodyElement, windowWidth, width);
      width = newWidths.newBodyWidth;
      windowWidth = newWidths.currentWindowWidth;
    });
  } else if(boxSizing == "border-box") {
   styleBorderBoxBody(bodyElement, sidebarElement);
    window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) { styleBorderBoxBody(bodyElement, sidebarElement); });
  }
}

function loadSidebar(sidebarId) {
  var sidebarElement = document.getElementById(sidebarId);
  sidebarElement.className = "sidebar";
  var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  styleBody(bodyElement, sidebarElement);
}
// end: my code


initSidebar();
```

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html {
      
    }

    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    body {
      font: 14px/1.1 Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 100%;
      
    }

    #editor {
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    }


    /* this class would be loaded from a CSS file I provide */
    .sidebar {
      border-color: green;
      border-style: solid;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<h1>Some UI from the existing website</h1>
<textarea id="editor">The text area</textarea>
```